# Run local script in remote host using crypto/ssh in golang

Tags: go, ssh

I am trying to replicate this command

`ssh user@host /bin/bash < dummy.sh`

using golang's crypto [library](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto).

I am opening a connection the remote host using ssh-agent. Then I am trying to run the command. Below is the snippet.

```
func executeSSHCmdToBuffer(cmd, hostname string, config *ssh.ClientConfig) (string, error) {
    conn, err := getSSHConnection(hostname, sshPort, config)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    session, err := conn.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer session.Close()

    var stdoutBuf bytes.Buffer
    session.Stdout = &stdoutBuf
    session.Run(cmd)
    output := stdoutBuf.String()
    log.Printf("SSH Output %s", output)
    return output, nil
}

func ExecuteSSHCommand(cmd, hostname string) (string, error) {
    sshAuth, err := sshAgent()
    log.Printf("Executing %s on %s", cmd, hostname)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("SSH Agent Failed to init: %s", err)
    }

    sshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: sshUser,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            sshAuth,
        },
        Timeout:         time.Duration(1 * time.Minute),
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }
    return executeSSHCmdToBuffer(cmd, hostname, sshConfig)
}

func main() {
    out, err := ExecuteSSHCommand("/bin/sh < dummy.sh", "test.example.com")

    if err != nil {
        log.Print("Cannot execute the command")
        log.Print(err)
    }

    log.Print(out)
}
```

This seems to give out empty output. Anyone have an idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried executing a simple command like `ls` to see if you get anything back? You can also try something like this https://github.com/marcsantiago/ringzer0team/blob/7acca0ad566f76ecf26053fa3269b27d241b253c/challege130/challege_130.go#L143

Comment: Also Session.Run() can fail. You're not checking for an error
https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Session.Run so `session.Run(cmd)` should become `if err := session.Run(cmd); err != nil{//DO SOMETHING WITH ERROR}`

Comment: Also I'm not sure `/bin/sh < dummy.sh` is correct.. why are you redirecting the executable `sh` to the shell file??? https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file